# wxPython Tray Icon : Exit on call from another Thread or Func

Tags: python, python-3.x, event-handling, wxpython, keyboard-events

I have a **wxPython TaskbarIcon** class with no other Parent window, except a Tray Icon, since it runs as a sort of background process. Provided below is a complete working example -->

```
import subprocess as sp
import wx.adv
from threading import Thread, Event
import os, signal

####### Create Tray Icon #######
def create_menu_item(menu, label, func):
    item = wx.MenuItem(menu, -1, label)
    menu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, func, id=item.GetId())
    menu.Append(item)
    return item

class TaskBarIcon(wx.adv.TaskBarIcon):
    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.frame = frame
        super(TaskBarIcon, self).__init__()
        self.set_icon(TRAY_ICON)
        self.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_UP, self.Run_Now)
        self.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_TASKBAR_RIGHT_DCLICK, self.on_exit)
        
    def CreatePopupMenu(self):
        menu = wx.Menu()
        create_menu_item(menu, 'Open Log_File', self.GoTo_Log)
        menu.AppendSeparator()
        create_menu_item(menu, 'Exit', self.on_exit)
        return menu

    def set_icon(self, path):
        icon = wx.Icon(path)
        self.SetIcon(icon, TRAY_TOOLTIP)
        
    def GoTo_Log(self, event):
        print("Log File will be Opened -- :)\n")
        # sp.Popen(["explorer.exe", LogFile])
        
    def Run_Now(self, event):
        # Run my task
        print("Running Now...")
    
    def on_exit(self, event):
        print('exiting . . . ')
        wx.CallAfter(self.Destroy)
        self.frame.Close(True)
        self.RemoveIcon()
        os.kill(pid, signal.SIGBREAK)

class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame= wx.Frame(None)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        sysTray= TaskBarIcon(frame)
        print("Moved to Sys Tray !\n")
        return True

################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

I want here to add the convenience to exit (close SysTray) on keypress (say 'F7'). I first decided to Bind EVT_KEY_DOWN with a method to detect keypress and then call *on_exit*. But It took me a while to realize that *TaskBarIcon* does not support EVT_KEY_DOWN, since there's no parent window !
Below is a my func to detect keypress ('F7') :

```
import keyboard, os, signal

def DetectEND(Force_END = False):
    #Long Press "F7" button to Terminate this Background Application
    if keyboard.is_pressed('f7') or Force_END:
        print("'f7' press detected | Ending Service ...") 
        # cleanHandlers(B_Log) # OR some other cleaning activities before quitting
        os.kill(pid, signal.SIGBREAK) # Using this instead of quit() since this would not run in the main thread !
        return True
    return False
```

Basically, I then just tried to use the above as a **Thread** to look up for the keypress and when returned True... wanted to communicate to the *TaskBarIcon* instance to call the *self.on_exit* method, but here too cannot figure out how to communicate without an Event binder !

Also, I am new to this **wxpython** and so... do not have any proper idea about the "MainLooping" of the wxpython... or else would have set up an threading.Event(), making the *DetectEND func* to set the Event when True, and then to check for *Event.is_set()* in the TaskBarIcon class, But I do know that this loop is way different from working on simple while True loops !!

Apart from the approaches mentioned above... I tried other ways too, like ***wx.CallAfter()*** from the DetectEND func itself and some global hotkey method, but None did work in this case or sometimes I could not figure out the implementation.

*THANK YOU -- for staying with me till this end !*

At last would appreciate any method that gets the job done ... and a Windows-specific method would even be too Great.

*Some other methods just thought of by me -- like one that does not involve threading (or) a way to bind a Key_down event to TaskBarIcon (or) a workaround for the CallAfter to call the *self.on_exit* method from another non-class function... (does not matter)*

Comment: Without wishing to rain on your parade, is it really a good idea to assign F7 (for example) exclusively to ending your program i.e. removing the ability for any other program to use F7 when your code is running?

Comment: I agree that this might not be a good idea for my specific use case... but this can also go on for like -- If a particular condition is met, then communicate to the SysTray to exit from a non-class func or similar... And for the _'f7'_ keypress, This is an like an autoscript than I usually require to run the whole day... and making it more easy to end would save a lot of time for me !

Comment: I'd probably look at listening on a port or pipe, or test for a /tmp/file. Then use another process to activate it, which could be run on request, via `autokey` or from another process on some condition.